# The databases in /usr/share/applications cannot be updated

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, mime-type, file-association

I m trying to perform File association to register my custom file extension for my application(ex: if I do `xdg-open myFile.myExtension`, it should launch my app). I m following this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/file_formats#custom-mime-type-all-users) to do it.
I have created a .desktop file under the location /usr/share/applications. Now to update the desktop database If I run the command: `update-desktop-database /usr/share/applications`, then it does not update the database and says:

```
The databases in /usr/share/applications cannot be updated
```

How can I resolve this?
This is my StartupLinux.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
MimeType=application/x-demo
Name=StartupLinux
Exec=/home/<user>/MyWorkspace/StartupLinux %f
```

> /home//MyWorkspace/StartupLinux.sh successfully launches my
> application from the terminal

This is my application-x-demo.xml file
[image]
I have tried logging out and in again, but it still does not work.

I have tried these links, but they don't work for me. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192204 [Unity launcher won't update the shortcuts after update-desktop-database (only after log out)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434269/unity-launcher-wont-update-the-shortcuts-after-update-desktop-database-only-af)

Comment: @Nmath I have edited the question, can u check now.

Comment: Can you also add the `.xml` file you created in `/usr/share/mime/packages`? For the commands that your instructions advise to run as root, are you using sudo?

Comment: yes, I m using sudo. I have added the .xml file

Comment: Hmmm.. Maybe there's a permissions issue? The .xml and .desktop files should probably have 644 permissions. You might also try putting the script somewhere other than a user's home folder. And also make sure that the script is executable.

Comment: I updated the ~/.local/share/applications(I guess it had some unupdated changes) with sudo and now I am able to update the desktop database under /usr/share/applications. But the file association is not working. The command "gio mime application/x-demo" gives me the correct registered application(my application) but If I run the command "gio info myFile.axsd | grep "standard::content-type"", it gives me the content type as text/plain and not application/x-demo. Any help here?